# filling a array with random numbers between 0-9 in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [filling a array with uniqe random numbers between 0-9 in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688044/filling-a-array-with-uniqe-random-numbers-between-0-9-in-c-sharp)

I have a array like "page[100]" and i want to fill it with random numbers between 0-9 in c#...
how i can do this?
i used :

```
IEnumerable<int> UniqueRandom(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive)
{
    List<int> candidates = new List<int>();
    for (int i = minInclusive; i <= maxInclusive; i++)
    {
        candidates.Add(i);
    }
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (candidates.Count > 1)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(candidates.Count);
        yield return candidates[index];
        candidates.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

this way :

```
int[] page = UniqueRandom(0,9).Take(array size).ToArray();
```

but it just gave me 9 unique random numbers but i need more.
how i can have a array with random numbers that are not all the same?

Comment: That code is over-complicated. Look back at the initial requirements.

Comment: You can't have 100 unique integers between 0 and 9

Comment: And it was him, and there are answers on it...

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? This one and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688044/filling-a-array-with-uniqe-random-numbers-between-0-9-in-c-sharp

Comment: i'm sorry...i'm newbi and i think my question needed to be change and i changed it...

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
int[] page = new int[100];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < page.Length; ++i)
  page[i] = rnd.Next(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random(); //add some seed
int[] randNums = new int[100]; //100 is just an example
for (int i = 0; i < randNums.Length; i++)
    randNums[i] = r.Next(10);
```

Comment: This will not draw numbers from [0, 9].

Comment: @Joey: You are right. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of 100 numbers and draw from a pool of 10 different ones. How would you expect there to be no duplicates?

Don't overcomplicate the thing, just write what needs to be written. I.e.:

1. Create the array
2. Loop over the size of it
3. Put a random number between from [0, 9] in the array.

Comment: exactly i want do that...but how?
i try so many way but i just give same integer...