# how to write a certain array item multiple times

Tags: c#

So I have myself an array like this one:

```
int masterNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 7);
        int childNumber;
        int[] fieldArray = new int[] {masterNumber, childNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 7)};
```

So now i'd like to write the master number to my console ONLY ONCE using Console.WriteLine(); and I'd like to write the random childNumber 99 times to the console, each childNumber with it's own value between 1 and 7. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a method to populate the `fieldArray`  with that master number and `99` random number or you just want to print the  same `childNumber` 99 times?

Comment: What about just using `Console.WriteLine(fieldArray[0])` and then using a `for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) Console.WriteLine(fieldArray[1])` ???

Comment: I'm looking to populate the fieldArray with my master number and 99 random numbers yes.

Comment: Have not try any sample, you can start here C# For Loops 
 https://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Comment: Take a read in [looping](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2064/looping#t=20170228062156478471) and you might find a way to do this.

Comment: Linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696861/filling-a-array-with-random-numbers-between-0-9-in-c-sharp (as dup) shows how to fill such array with all random numbers. Presumably you should be able to set first item to whatever you want afterwards. If that is beyond your current abilities - try asking new question "how to set first element of an array" (no guarantees of result so :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to use fieldArray if you have "masterNumber" & "childNumber". But I think, you can do it in this way...

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
int masterNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 7);
int childNumber;
int[] fieldArray = new int[] { masterNumber, childNumber = randomNumber.Next(1, 7) };

Console.Write("Master Number " + masterNumber);
int i = 0;
while (i < 99)
{
   Console.Write("Child Number " + childNumber);
   Console.WriteLine(i);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Read the comments, this is not what OP wants.

Comment: "I'm looking to populate the fieldArray with my master number and 99 random numbers"... Array with 2 elements unlikely to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @Alisson .. Question is edited now .. and I answered it before edits. :)

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 it's not a big problem at all, but thanks for trying to help.